# Reading from file doesn't return anything, but it is accessed

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp ;
    int n,i,x[n];

    fp=fopen("fin.txt","r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        puts("Error opening filename.txt");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

    fscanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        fscanf("%d",&x[i]);
    printf("%d ",n);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to read from a file, although it doesn't print anything. I checked to see if it opens the file, and it does. Although no data returned. Why is that? 
Input file: 5 3 4 5 8 2
-------------------------------------------EDIT : The file is the project's folder.

Comment: You don’t check the return from `fscanf()` — you should.

Comment: How does the compiler know the size of the array `x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not calling `fscanf` correctly.

The first argument to `fscanf` is a `FILE *` for the file you want to read from.  You've omitted this argument, so the function is taking the string you passed in as the first argument and attempting to read it as a `FILE` object.

Pass `fp` as the first arguments in each of the calls.

This also isn't doing what you expect:

```
int n,i,x[n];
```

This doesn't mean that the size of the array `x` is tied to the value of `n`.  It means the size of `x` is set to the *current* value of `n`, which hasn't been assigned a value yet.

Move the declaration of `x` to after a value has been read in for `n`.

```
int rval = fscanf(fp, "%d",&n);
if (rval != 1) return EXIT_FAILURE;
int x[n];
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    fscanf(fp, "%d",&x[i]);
```